# Loop through unordered list and perform operation on each node Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of products in my store. Each product has a price in a div. I need to find the price of each product, and calculate a sales price of 30%, and append it to the price in red.

I can do the DOM manipulation for this, but I cant figure out how to loop over the products. This code below appends the sales price of ONLY the first product to all of the products in the list.

Working Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/m5fxnLqp/1/

Sample HTML:

```
<ul class="ProductList">
  <li class="product">
    <div class="ProductPrice">$9.99</div>
  </li>
  <li class="product">
    <div class="ProductPrice">$10.99</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the DOM Manipulation:

```
//find the price and convert to decimal to work with
var price = $(".ProductPrice").text();
var priceFormat = price.replace("$", "");
var priceNum = parseFloat(priceFormat).toFixed(2);

//calculate the price discount 
var priceDiscount = priceNum * .30;
var priceFinal = priceDiscount.toFixed(2);

// Append the formatted price to the div
var formattedPrice = '<div style="color:red;"> $' + priceFinal + '</div>';
$(".ProductPrice").append( formattedPrice );
```

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/hunan131/3earxn2o/) is a working example. I've modified the html a bit. Be sure to also check out the useful answers below.

Comment: Awesome, thanks guys. What about using pure JS. The each function makes it so easy, i was struggling to do this in a for loop!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use **.each()** to loop through `".ProductPrice"`

```
//find the price and convert to decimal to work with
   $(".ProductPrice").each(function(){
        var price = $(this).text();
        var priceFormat = price.replace("$", "");
        var priceNum = parseFloat(priceFormat).toFixed(2);

        //calculate the price discount 
        var priceDiscount = priceNum - priceNum * .30;
        var priceFinal = priceDiscount.toFixed(2);

        // Append the formatted price to the div
        var formattedPrice = '<div style="color:red;"> $' + priceFinal + '</div>';
        $(this).append( formattedPrice );

    });
```

[**Working Demo Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/m5fxnLqp/2/)

Note: This code will append the new price after discount by using

```
var priceDiscount = priceNum - priceNum * .30;
```

if you need just a discount return it back to your code

```
var priceDiscount = priceNum * .30;
```

and I think you need to use

```
$(this).closest('product').append( formattedPrice );
```

instead of

```
$(this).append( formattedPrice );
```

the deference between `$(this).append( formattedPrice );`  and `$(this).closest('product').append( formattedPrice );`

`$(this).append( formattedPrice );` html after append

```
<div class="ProductPrice">
     $9.99
     <div style="color:red;"> $6.99</div>
</div>
```

`$(this).closest('product').append( formattedPrice );` html after append

```
<li class="product">
    <div class="ProductPrice">$9.99</div>
    <div style="color:red;"> $6.99</div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the .each function: http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 0):

I update your code using `each()` function:

https://jsfiddle.net/m5fxnLqp/4/

Now it works.